# How to update array of key/value pairs into a mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Background:** I have an array of objects sent from Vue Axios.  These objects are key value pairs which is stored in the req.body.

**Req.body**

```
keyValue:  [{key:"some key", value:"some value"}, {key:"some key2", value:"some value2"}]
```

**Note**:   I can expect to receive a req.body with a numerous amount objects withing the array. I can not access the "key" and "value" in the objects without adding a [ ] or req.body.keyValue[0].

How can I dynamically add each object's "key" and "value" into mongoose without having to explicitly call a specific object?

**I am trying to do something like this:**(failed attempt)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Schema = new Schema({
  Pair: [{
    Key: String,
    Value: Number
  }]
});

router.post("/",  (req, res) => {
 User.update({},
  {$push:
  {Pair:{
        Key: req.body.keyValue.key,
         Value: req.body.keyValue.value
       }
      }
    }, 
  (err,result)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).send('Error')
    }else{
      res.status(200).send(result);
    }
  })
}
```

I hope I was able to explain well enough.  Let me know if there is any confusions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that when your call `req.body.keyValue.key` and `req.body.keyValue.value`, they are in a javascript array `req.body.keyValue[]`.

Presuming that the `req.body.keyValue` will be always a valid array with the `{ key : '...', value : '...' }` you can use the [MongoDB $each operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) to update your document.

As:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Schema = new Schema({
  Pair: [{
    key: String,
    value: Number
  }]
});

router.post("/",  (req, res) => {
  User.update(
    {},
    {
      $push: {
        Pair:{
          $each : req.body.keyValue
        }
      }
    }, 
    (err,result)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send('Error')
      }else{
        res.status(200).send(result);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Now just be careful that `req.body.keyValue` has the right capitalization on each element, so you don't have `*K*ey` and/or `*k*ey`, that will not match your schema.   =]

### Edit

Just to explain how the $each operator will work, see the following example:

```
req.body = {
  keyValue : [
    { key : "key1", value : 1 },
    { key : "key2", value : 2 }
  ]
};
```

Document in `User` collection before the update:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  Pair : [
    { key : "key_A", value : 99 }
  ]
}
```

After the `.update()` with the `$each` operator, the expected updated document:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  Pair : [
    { key : "key_A", value : 99 },
    { key : "key1", value : 1 },
    { key : "key2", value : 2 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In your example it doesn't save the req.body.keyValue to the key and value property in the Pair schema.  Is there a way to save one the Schema structure with $each?  Couldnt find an example. Thanks!

Comment: The `$each` operator, will interact with each element from the array by itself on the MongoDB side.

I presumed that you were using the schema when you are constructing the `User` variable, and in that case, mongoose will apply the schema on each interaction with the collection.

I will edit the answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

**User Schema**

```
userId: {
    type: String
},
password: {
    type: String
},
friends: [{
    userId: String,
    followSent: Boolean,
    followAccepted: Boolean,
    followbackSent: Boolean,
    followbackAccepted: Boolean,
    inchats: Boolean
}]
```

**Update Code**

```
userModel.updateOne({ userId: "MyId" , "friends.userId": "frndId"},{
$set: {
        'friends.$.followSent': true}},(err, docs) => {
                   
        })
```